RuntimeError: This event loop is already running when using AsyncioConnection
With the following code I am trying to connect to my Rabbit instance using the pika AsyncioConnection adapter
import asyncio

import pika
from pika.adapters.asyncio_connection import AsyncioConnection


async def start_consuming():
    connection = AsyncioConnection(
        parameters=pika.URLParameters(AMQP_URL),
    )
    connection.ioloop.run_forever()


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(start_consuming())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Once the code hits the line when connection.ioloop.run_forever() is invoked it prints this error:
  File "/Users/asant/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/asant/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/asant/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 685, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/asant/Desktop/enrichment-consumer/app/app.py", line 31, in main
    await asyncio.gather(start_consuming())
  File "/Users/asant/Desktop/enrichment-consumer/app/app.py", line 27, in start_consuming
    channel.ioloop.run_forever()
  File "/Users/asant/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 628, in run_forever
    self._check_running()
  File "/Users/asant/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 620, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

